# SQL Update with a Group by Statement not working

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, sum, sql-update

I've got two temp tables.

In table `@due_cte` I have a series of `Customer_Ids`, followed by `payment` amounts collected throughout various points in the code.

The `@work` table has a lot of various columns including `hist_amt_due.`

What I want to do is update `@work` with the amt_due from `@due_cte` but `group/sum` all of them by `customer_ID`

My original code:

```
update  @work
set     hist_amt_due = sum(isnull(due_amt,0)
from    @work w
join    @due_cte d on w.pmt_customer_no = d.pmt_customer_no
group by  w.pmt_customer_no
```

followed by error messages:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
```

After some digging i found that i should use an inner join so i attempted this, but this too is still not working.

```
update  @work
set     hist_amt_due = isnull(d.due_amt,0)
from    @work w
inner join  (SELECT pmt_customer_no, sum(isnull(due_amt,0)) from @due_cte group by pmt_customer_no) AS d on w.pmt_customer_no = d.pmt_customer_no
```

Error Message:

```
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'd'.
```

and

```
Invalid column due_amount
```

I am at a loss about how to imperilment this.

sample data:

```
pmt_customer_no  |  due_amt
1                   50
2                   30
3                   0
4                   30
2                   10
1                   20
5                   80
```

`@work` should be updated - where customer number is **1** the `due_amout` should be: **70**, where it's **2** then `due_amount` should be **40**, etc.

Comment: In your first query you don't have a closing parenthesis for the SUM function. The reason this is challenging is because what you are doing is very non-standard in relational data. You are storing aggregated data across a group of rows for each row in the group. This concept is fraught with issues because getting and keeping this value accurate is challenging. You have to properly handle all inserts, updates and deletes.

Comment: Yes, this is so. However the data was built before me, we've got a series of changing if statements for the way the data was stored over the years. With each if statement we insert the customer_ID and due amount for that  given scenario - at the end we need to sum all of them to make sure we account for the way data was tracked/kept over the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update w set hist_amt_due = d.s
from @work w
join (select pmt_customer_no, sum(isnull(due_amt, 0)) s 
      from @due_cte group by pmt_customer_no)d on w.pmt_customer_no = d.pmt_customer_no
```

Comment: The logic seems to be good, and no errors occur. When I see what is in my temp table `pmt_customer_no due_amt 
60122304 558.00` however when the data runs for that given `customer_Id` the field shows `hist_amt_due
0.00`

Comment: Try selecting `select * 
from @work w
join (select pmt_customer_no, sum(isnull(due_amt, 0)) s 
      from @due_cte group by pmt_customer_no)d on w.pmt_customer_no = d.pmt_customer_no `

Comment: The select statement seems to work fine. (it shows the hist_amt_due with a zero to start) and the s column with a 558. I'm not sure why the select would work but the update wouldn't.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR, check for triggers

Comment: It's a report procedure - with a final select statement, I took a look and don't see any triggers on it. What else could the issue be.

Comment: May be it is changed after update somewhere. If select returns correct values then update should work too.

Comment: I got it to work. It was an if/else issue (code was being skipped). Thank you for your help.